# How do I update rails in my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-3-upgrade

I have a Rails 3.0.4 Application, but my server works with Rails 3.0.6

How do I update rails in my app?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a gemfile?

If so it's simply a matter of updating the line in your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
```

And then running from the command line:

```
bundle update
```

to update gem dependencies

```
rake db:migrate
```

in case there's any database changes

```
bundle install
```

Install the gems.